# hdfs group permission doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs, redhat, cloudera-cdh

I'm using `Hadoop 2.2.0` and found that `hdfs` group permission configs don't work like the linux filesystem

```
$hadoop fs -ls /user
drwxrwx---   - data   data                0 2014-06-27 11:18 /user/data

$whoami
raw

$groups
raw data
```

this directory belongs to the user `data` and the group `data`.
Then when another user `raw`, who is the member of the group `data`, tries to list the directory `/user/data` on `hdfs` the following exception is raised:

```
ls: Permission denied: user=langxian.chen, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/user/data":data:data:drwxrwx---
```

any idea why?

Comment: Set permissions for `/user/data` as 775

Comment: This is not working, the problem persist, Any other idea?

Comment: The problem occurs in `CDH 5` running in `RedHat`